# Filling space in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In `RelativeLayout` how do I make a `widget` fill the space between a Left border of `parent` and Right border of another `widget` completely?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vsname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:hint="@string/entername"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vsdesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsname"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:hint="@string/shrtdesc"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsdesc"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:prompt="@string/icon_prompt" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsdesc"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/memmory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:text="1000 MB"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/cache"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/cache_size_picker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/data"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/data_size_picker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/system"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/system_size_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make `@id/memmory` fill the entire space between the Right border of its parent and `@id/spinner`.

```
 ---------------------------------------------
|                           |                 |
|                           |                 |
|                           |                 |
|                           |    ImageView    |
|       Stuff               |                 |
|                           |                 |
|                           |                 |
|                           |-----------------
|                           |    TextView     |
----------------------------------------------
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                   Stuff                     |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|                                             |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

This is what it should look like, notice that the TextView is centre aligned. I tried using compundDrawable for textview but sadly it don't show up when I inflate my dialog.

Comment: @Akki posted layout code

Comment: try    
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner" in @+id/memmory TextView

Comment: Try to show an image of how do you wish you layout to look like.

Comment: @Akki that will make the textview to occupy the space but I since I cant use fill_parent, it will align the text to the right of the space, I want it in centre.

Comment: A prototype/snapshot of your requirement will definitely solve this

Comment: @Akki wouldn't work because its wrapped to its content, that's what I was trying to say..

Comment: @Sreeram added prototype

Comment: if fill_parent is solving your problem y you are not using that

Comment: @Akki It will fillup the entire screen. Are you sure that you know what you are talking about?

Comment: @BinoyBabu yes offcourse check my answer

Comment: seems great approach happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `ImageView` and added `android:drawableTop` attribute to `TextView`. This works as intented.

```
<!--    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seticonimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/cm7_icon" /> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_and_memory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:drawableTop = "@drawable/cm7_icon"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="1000 MB"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside one relative layout would be better in getting such a screen,

Image -  parent top - true , Parent right - true, Center Vertical - true, layout width&height - wrapcontent

Text View - Layout below - Image, Left Align - Image, Right Align - Image, layout width&height - wrapcontent

Stuff 1 -  top align - Image, bottom align - text view, left of - image ,layout width&height - wrapcontent

stuff2 - bottom of - stuff1, layout width&height - fill parent